# Query: Purpose of splitting circuit between MPLS/Internet

Tags: mpls, isp

I have a new 100mb line at work that has a 80mb(MPLS)/20mb(Internet) split. I just want to confirm my understanding of this. The MPLS connects us to our HQ in London and with the current split that gives us 80mb of bandwidth to our other offices, does this 80mb also provide any bandwidth for internet access or is that 80mb only for access to our other offices?

Comment: You should edit your question to include the router model and configuration. Likely, the 80 Mbps is on one subinterface, and the 20 Mbps is on another.

Comment: Ask your ISP/Carrier if Internet traffic is allowed to burst above 20Mbps in case of no/low MPLS traffic.

Comment: Hi, I am afraid I am unable to this as the routers (Cisco 2911) are managed by our ISP (Chess Telecom) - I have no access to them. I am currently querying this with them and I will let you know what I get, My other question was with the 80mb MPLS I am only communicating with my connected offices, im not using that to also reach the internet am I? Thanks for your time & help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the vendor/hardware, technically the provider could set this up either way, so there could be a hard limit of 80 Mbps MPLS/20 Mbps Internet or they could allow the unused bandwidth to be used by the other service.   Contractually, the provider will likely have tied this down in the terms of use and configured the hardware to implement that policy.  If you have read access to the provider’s hardware which implements the policy, then please post the config along with the vendor and hardware model and we can advise on how the provider has implemented this.  Let us know the provider and service you have purchased.  Someone may be able to comment if they use the same service.  I’d also advise you check your provider’s documentation or contact them.  There is no standard implementation for this, so without this info we can only guess.  If I were to take a guess, I would say the provider had set hard limits, so no more than 80 Mbps on the MPLS and 20 Mbps on the Internet as each of the two can incur third-party costs and the provider needs to budget accordingly.

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to provide more information to the OP and any future readers.  As it stands, there's not much useful here.